# azure start page signalR

Tags: c#, html, azure, signalr, persistent-connection

I have created a simple SignalR web site (copied from a book). I have declared the index.html page as startup page.

When I run it from within Visual Stufio (using IIS Express) it works fine.

When I publish to Azure the index.html page is just ignored and the website starts from the default azure page!

It says: "This website has been successfully created
There's nothing here yet, but Microsoft Azure makes it simple to publish"

You can try it here: 
http://biddingonline.azurewebsites.net/

Now if you add index.html, the correct page shows, but the application doesn't work properly...

Try http://biddingonline.azurewebsites.net/index.html and you can see the source code.

Any clue welcome

Comment: looking over the javascript, it looks like SignalR is supposed to update the text with "12333 by Jonesy" (for example). It seems to work fine.

Comment: I see the correct site under this [URL](http://biddingonline.azurewebsites.net/)